# GUID error - InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Decimal' to type 'System.Int64'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, guid

I am using GUID identifiers to track certain activities in cookies and checking to see if it exists in the db, but I am getting the error

> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Decimal' to type 'System.Int64'.

Here is my code

```
string Cookies2 = Request.Cookies["Upload_Guid"].ToString();

Guid Cookie_Guid = Guid.Parse(Cookies2);// GEt the value of cookie and parse it to a GUID

var GID_Variable = await  _context.Upload_Transaction
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Cookie_GUID  == Cookie_Guid);
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the code that is throwing the `InvalidCastException`? Have you looked at what the value of `Cookies2` is?  I would expect the exception from this block of code to be something like a `FormatException` if the string is not a valid GUID. Have you tried Guid.TryParse and checked to see if it can parse it?

Comment: Yes the cookies2 is a GUID in the breakpoints, and its the EF database read object that is throwing the error.  I read up on tryparse but cant get my head around it

Comment: So the exception is coming from the line: `_context.Upload_Transaction.SingleOrDefault`, can you post the code for your EF model?  Is `Cookie_GUID` an actual `Guid`? Can you just run the line `_context.Upload_Transaction.Take(1)` without exception?

Comment: Yes it was actually a GUID

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it had nothing to do with the code, apparently in my database, I had a field which was image size (Int) and in my code, it was Long, so I changed it from Int to BigInt and its ok now

Hence the error here

```
var GID_Variable = await  _context.Upload_Transaction
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Cookie_GUID  == Cookie_Guid);
```

Although the code does not show the size field
thanks